# iOS zip performance

Tags: ios, performance, zip

It seems info about zip performance on iOS is a bit sparse, so I'm hoping someone can elaborate a bit on the subject (or do some testing since I do not have that option).

I've written a pure C project for use in an iOS application (for iPad 2/3) which uses some pretty large data files (5x ~300 MB) and I know these can be compressed quite well (5x ~90 MB). Currently the application will select one of the 5 unzipped data files and memory map it - this can be changed on the fly.

Because the data files are unzipped this action happens pretty much instantly, but it's quite a large app, so obviously I'm wondering - what if we unzipped the data files on the fly? How long would a switch (delete current data file, unzip new data file) take?

I'm hoping the answer can also be helpful to others who'd like a quick lookup for iOS zip performance.

Comment: I would guess that there are too many variables in play to give an accurate answer. What library/code will be used to unzip? What other operations will be going on at the same time (this would include OS tasks)? How much memory will the app be using in addition to the resources for this task? Etc, etc. Testing is the only way to come to a answer, and even then the results would probably not be of use outside of the context of your app.

Comment: All true and I agree apart from the comment about use outside of my application - I'd be happy with an indication of performance. Something that could be used to tell "Is this feasible or not?". Like, are we talking 1 second or 30 seconds - I think that would be useful information to anyone looking for a quick, but not in-depth answer.

Comment: I am quite sure that it will take a lot to unzip 500MB file on iDevice, enough to make app look bad. How about distributing app with zipped files and then unzip them on first run? Or distribute app without any files and then download them from web server on first run/bootstrap? Does that seem like a good compromise?

Comment: @IvorPrebeg that's the solution we're looking at currently, so yes.

Comment: unless it is a game (gamers are used to these long "Loading" screens), iOS users expect sleek performance, so unless you can do some magic to trick user to do something else while uncompressing in background, I would not do it... If you can get jailbroken iphone, try to install unzip and use it with example file (or make someone do it for you, I don't have JB-ed one)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you should uncompress these files to the flash drive, not to the memory (since there is not too much memory on iDevice), so your app will require ~1Gb of free storage to run.
So, since this storage can not be used in any other good way, I would recommend to uncompress the data on the first run (and, probably, not deliver data files with the app but to download them from your site).
And, yes, decompressing ~500Mb file would take a while on iDevices.